# Выходит из цикла for в с#

Tags: c#

При компиляции цикл не выполняется так как задумано. Подскажите где опечатка или недочёт.

Вот код:

```
public IDrawMesh[] CreatePyramid(int cubsCount, int height,int canvWidth, Color color)
{
    int pasY = 0;
    int cubHeigth = height / cubsCount;
    int summ = (cubsCount*(coubsCount + 1)) / 2;
    int canvCenter = canvWeidth / 2;

    IDrawMesh[]meshes = new Square[cubsCount];
    for (int i = 1; i >= cubsCount; i++)//cubsCount при компиляции = 4
    {
        //Не важный код который не изменяет литерал i
    }

    return meshes;
}
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пример вызова

Comment: Приветствую, пример вызова можно посмотреть тут https://pastebin.com/UZy9ZWrc

Comment: Вам уже ниже расписали, у вас вызов CreatePyramid(4, 98, 100, Color.Blue), в первой итерации будет проверка 1 >= 4 - поэтому и выходит. нужно поменять i >= cubsCount на i <= cubsCount :)

Comment: Правил вопрос..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(1 >= 4) == false` - поэтому происходит выход из цикла, что не так? Возможно, вы хотели сделать условие `<=`, но просто перепутали.

Comment: не успел... Как всегда

Comment: Я дам свой ответ с некими правками для пользователя, вы не против?

Comment: Спасибо. И првда, исправил. Теперь работает. В логике правда все равно накосячил, не то что задумал рисует)